# Swift Vapor3 Raw SQL query with new connection

Tags: mysql, sql, swift, fluent, vapor

I'm attempting to use Vapor3 to perform *raw* SQL queries. The supplied documentation for this kind of thing is pretty vague on the website unfortunately.

Essentially I want to do something like:

```
router.get("example") { req -> Future<View> in
    let leaf = try request.make(LeafRenderer.self)

    // I can't get this next bit to work. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this? I seem to get all sorts of Xcode errors with .mysql, closures etc.
    let users = try request.withNewConnection(to: .mysql) { connection -> EventLoopFuture<[User]> 
       return try connection.raw("select * from users").all(decoding: User.self)
    }

    var context = [String: String]()
    context["user"] = users

    return leaf.render("example", context)
}
```

Any help on want I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code was failing because you aren't implementing the closure properly. Your route returns in the `let users...` closure so the second `return` is never reached.

This works:

```
router.get("example")
{
    insecure.get("example") {
        request -> Future<View> in
        return request.withNewConnection(to: .mysql) {
            connection in
            return connection.raw("select * from User").all(decoding: User.self).flatMap(to:View.self) {
                users in
                return try request.make(LeafRenderer.self).render("example",["users":users])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The changes are:

1. There's no need to define `leaf` until you need it.
2. The definition of `users` is now inside the closure.

Comment: Doh. Thanks heaps... Was getting completely confused with the auto completion and various errors from Xcode.